# Python: Merging files and removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have 3 excel files each with 4000 rows and 5 columns. I wish to combine the excel files in a data frame and remove duplicate rows. Subsequently, I wish to  publish the result as an excel file:

```
 import pandas as pd

 import numpy as np

 filenames = ['Sample_a.xlsx','Sample_b.xlsx','Sample_c.xlsx']

 dataframes = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in filenames]

 new_dataframe = df.dropduplicates(dataframes)
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: The variable `dataframes` in this case is just a list, it's not a merged dataframe. I suggest reading [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) on combining dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

After you convert the excel files to a list to `dataframes` variable you need to convert it to a data frame. I have found a solution hope you might see an answer here.

```
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filenames = ['csv/2009.xlsx', 'csv/2010.xlsx', 'csv/2011.xlsx']
olddf=pd.DataFrame()
for f in filenames:
    df=pd.read_excel(f)
    olddf=pd.concat([olddf,df]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`
```

Comment: It's good that you found a solution.  In general, it's good form to post your solution as a solution so that people can see where your difficulty was and learn from your answer.

Comment: Sure thing I'm new to Stack overflow. Form next answer i will try to do it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without being able to reproduce your results (we don't know what's in your files), but you are trying to eliminate the duplicates from a list of dataframes.  Shouldn't you be operating on the dataframes themselves?

```
new_dataframes = [df.drop_duplicates(d) for d in dataframes]
```

Comment: Let us say I have files with same rows:                                                                                "A B C D". I want to drop the same rows from the new data frame and get the output in a new excel file.